# OWIN token parsing fails on app pool restart

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, owin

We implemented an API that uses OWIN OAuth with Bearer tokens for authentication. We discovered that these tokens are invalidated after stopping and starting the application pool (but recycle is fine).

As the Identity is "not authenticated" and all properties are empty, we assume it has to do with the key used for encryption getting somehow lost. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx) tells me that these keys are auto-generated and then stored in the LSA and should be taken out of there again, but this seems not to happen.

Could this have to do with the pools running via a shared/predefined service user account in some way? (if so that would be pretty weird).

EDIT: I followed [this guide](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) btw.